# Nginx:two virtual host

Tags: nginx

One is a blog and another is a web app,use two virtual host for them with two second-level domain

blog.example.com

webapp.example.com

the vitual.conf file is under /etc/nginx/conf.d,include this in nginx configuration file,here is the virtual.conf

```
 ######################for blog##############################
    server {
            listen  80;
            server_name  blog.example.cn;
            access_log  /www/access_blog  main;
            location / {
                root   /www/blog;
                index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            }
            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            }
           # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            location ~ \.php$ {
             fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
             fastcgi_index   index.php;
             fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   /www/blog/$fastcgi_script_name;
             include        fastcgi_params;
          }
            location ~ /.ht {
                deny  all;
            }
    }
    #######################for web app#######################
    server {
            listen  80;
            server_name webapp.example.com; 
            access_log  /www/access_webapp  main;
            location / {
                root   /www/webapp;
                index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            }
            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            }
           # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            location ~ \.php$ {
             fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
             fastcgi_index   index.php;
             fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   /www/oclass/$fastcgi_script_name;
             include        fastcgi_params;
          }
            location ~ /.ht {
                deny  all;
            }
    }
```

the web app can serve normally,but when enter the address of https://blog.example.com then always turn to https://blog.example.com:8888

it seems that the nginx forwarding the request to the port 8888,so i change the server of blog to listen to port 8888,

```
#######################for web app#######################
server {
        listen  8888;
```

then it works,the nginx can serve the blog normally,(by the way the permission mode of direction /www is 755 )but how to solve this problem,for server of blog and web app can both listen 80?

Comment: Did you mean `https`? Because you have only defined `http` server blocks. The above configuration does not redirect to port 8888, which suggests the blog application is doing it itself.

Comment: Thank you so much!